# Different main text on different plots

Tags: r, plot

I frequently make functions in R that put out a plot. Many times I make different plots by changing one of the parameters, such as expected value or standard deviation. I do this so I can compare the plots.

I would really like R to change the main text on the plot, so as it is sensitive to the other parameters in the function.

Example:

```
QQplot <- function(samples, mu, sigma){
  X<- rnorm(samples, mu, sigma)
  Y<- rlnorm(samples, mu, sigma)
  plot(sort(X), sort(Y), main=????)
}
```

Her samples is number of simulations, mu is expected value go sigma is standard divination. I want the function to put out the plot, with the main title to be sensitive to the input values of mu and sigma. It would also be nice to have more in the title, but it would really help.

Or, it would also satisfy just to have mu and sigma printed below the plot. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it will be more clear if you let us know what functions u use to generate plot. Most of them got 'main' parameter, to set title of the graph. So u can redirect your mu and sigma there, like:

```
ExPlot <- function(sample, mu, sigma){ 
    plot(sample, main = paste('Mu: ', mu, ' sigma: ', sigma, sep='')) 
}
```

Comment: I have now changed the question giving an example. I have also tried your suggestion, but either I do something wrong or it doesn't work. Probably the first! :-)

Comment: @user7919 There was a missing comma in that code, which I've fixed.

Comment: Ou, sorry for that. I was typing from head. Thanks Thomas! :)